# How to extract data from Array in Dictionary?

Tags: arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to get a grasp of the VBA Dictionary.
I believe I have succeeded into storing the text of multiple cells into an array into the dictionary. But I can't find any way to get it out of there.
End goal is the ability to add multiple sources into 1 dictionary and then extract them by key or item or all at once into a new tab.

Here is the code I'm working on:

Sub tutorial_dictionary_Select()

```
'Must add reference to Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim dict As New Dictionary
dict.CompareMode = CompareMethod.TextCompare

Dim source As Worksheet
Set source = ActiveSheet

Dim last_row As Long
last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim last_col As Long
last_col = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Dim i As Long, n As Long
Dim hasHeader As Boolean
Dim arr(0 To 99) As Variant

If IsNumeric(Range("B1").Value) Or IsNumeric(Range("C1").Value) Then
        i = 0
    Else
        hasHeader = True
        i = 1
        n = 1
            For Each rngCell In Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, last_col))
                arr(n) = rngCell.Text
                'MsgBox arr(n)
                Range("I" & n) = arr(n)
                Range("J" & n) = n
                n = n + 1
            Next rngCell
End If

Dim strVal As String
Dim Item(0 To 99) As Variant
Dim header As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngTemp As Range

For Each rngCell In Range(Cells(1 + i, 1), Cells(last_row, 1))
    i = i + 1
    strVal = rngCell.Text
    If Not dict.Exists(strVal) Then
            n = 0
            For Each headerCell In Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, last_col))
                n = n + 1
                Item(n) = headerCell.Text
                MsgBox headerCell.Text
            Next headerCell
            dict(strVal) = Item
    Else
        MsgBox "already exists"
    End If
Next rngCell


sFruit = InputBox("Check value of key")
MsgBox "The value of " & sFruit & " is " & dict(sFruit)
```

The message box gives a type mismatch and I feel like I've tried everything to get those values either put in a cell or debugged and I'm clueless.

As you can see, the code it totally flexible checking for height and width (and a header). And it generates the correct items and their position in the array on the right:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFSho.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign the same array to every key in the dictionary, you have to create a new one each time.

```vb
Sub tutorial_dictionary_Select()

    'Must add reference to Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    dict.CompareMode = CompareMethod.TextCompare

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    Dim last_row As Long, last_col As Long, start_row As Long
    Dim hasHeader As Boolean, i As Integer, iRow As Long

    last_row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    last_col = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    Debug.Print "last_col", last_col

    ' check for header
    hasHeader = True
    start_row = 2
    For i = 2 To last_col
        If IsNumeric(ws.Cells(1, i)) Then
            hasHeader = False
            start_row = 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim ar As Variant, sKey As String
    For iRow = start_row To last_row

        sKey = ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Text

        If Not dict.Exists(sKey) Then
            ar = Array()
            ReDim ar(last_col)
            For i = 2 To last_col
                ar(i) = ws.Cells(iRow, i)
            Next
            dict(sKey) = ar
        End If

    Next

    Dim sFruit As String
    sFruit = InputBox("Check value of key")
    MsgBox "The value of " & sFruit & " is " & dict(sFruit)(3)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes!! That did the trick! I've been stuck on this for days, thank you so much.

Could you maybe elaborate what this code does? The script will run without the first line, but not without the second.

```
    ar = Array()
    ReDim ar(lastCol)
```

In case a key already exists, I want to add the amounts of the 2nd entry to what was already stored in the dictionary. I was able to figure this out myself:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim dict As New Dictionary
Set dict = New Dictionary
dict.CompareMode = TextCompare

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim lastCol As Long
lastCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Dim i As Integer
Dim startRow As Long
startRow = 2

Dim ar As Variant
Dim sKey As String

For iRow = startRow To lastRow
    sKey = ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Text
    If Not dict.Exists(sKey) Then
        ar = Array()
        ReDim ar(lastCol)
        For i = 2 To lastCol
            ar(i) = ws.Cells(iRow, i)
        Next
        dict(sKey) = ar
    Else
        ar = dict(sKey)
        For i = 2 To lastCol
            ar(i) = ar(i) + ws.Cells(iRow, i)
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Is this the right way to do it? I expected to do something like dict(sKey)(3) = dict(sKey)(3) + ws.Cells(iRow, 3) but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've been trying to store my item + properties into an array and then multiple items in an array in a dictionary if that makes sense.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim dict As New Dictionary
Set dict = New Dictionary
dict.CompareMode = TextCompare

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim lastCol As Long
lastCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Dim i As Long, u As Long
Dim startRow As Long
startRow = 2

Dim ar As Variant, items As Variant, item As Variant
Dim sKey As String
Dim itemAdded As Boolean

For iRow = startRow To lastRow
    sKey = ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Text
    item = ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Text
    If Not dict.Exists(sKey) Then
        MsgBox "adding new customer"
        items = Array()
        ReDim items(99)
        ar = Array()
        ReDim ar(lastCol)
        '--------------------
        For i = 2 To lastCol
            ar(i) = ws.Cells(iRow, i)
        Next
        items(0) = ar
        dict(sKey) = items
    Else
        MsgBox "customer already exists"
        items = dict(sKey)
        For u = LBound(items) To UBound(items)
            If item = items(u)(2) Then
                MsgBox "item already exists"
                ar = items(u)
                For i = 3 To lastCol
                    ar(i) = ar(i) + ws.Cells(iRow, i)
                Next
                items(u) = ar
                dict(sKey) = items
                itemAdded = True
            End If
        Next
        If Not itemAdded = True Then
            MsgBox "adding new item"
            For i = 2 To lastCol
                ar(i) = ws.Cells(iRow, i)
            Next
            items(u) = ar
            dict(sKey) = items
        End If
    End If
Next
```

What is working is that I can recall Items(u)(2) and see the name of an item. But the *If item = items(u)(2) Then* statement is giving me a type mismatch even though it passes as true on the first loop, why? I tried declaring as String and as Variant but neither combination is working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3gnP.jpg